# How can I store a byte[] list in viewstate?

Tags: asp.net, viewstate, byte

I want to store some byte[] to ViewState. For example I want to store a list of FileBytes. How can I do it?

Answer (score 3):

I haven't actually tried this with a list, but it should be pretty simple:

```
List<byte> myByteList;
// do something here to load list
ViewState["Bytes"] = myByteList
```

When you need to get it out:

```
List<byte> myByteList = (List<byte>)ViewState["Bytes"];
```

Edit: Changed from byte[] to List.

Comment: excuse me, I mean list<byte[]> MyBytesArray, and I want store this list in ViewStat

Comment: Should be the same code, just changing the data type. Again, I haven't tried it with a collection, but I beleive it will work. I will modify my answer with the new data type.